# VB.Net 2010 "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when declaring a variable from a Dictionary with a list as the value

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, nullreferenceexception, vb.net-2010

This is a school project for Programming (not an assessment or assignment, so I'm not cheating) where I have to make a 7-segment display<sup>Source 1</sup>. I decided instead of going the traditional way and manually setting each `RectangeShape` to visible on each button pressed to display a number; store the corresponding number and which `RectangleShape`(s) to turn on as a key-value pair in a dictionary. I have some knowledge of Python, so this is where I got the idea from. My form<sup>Source 2</sup> has 7 `RectangleShape`(s) and 10 `Button`(s). Just as an experiment since it's my first time working with `Dictionaries` and `Lists` in `VB.net`, I decided to only try it out for the number `1` for now (`shp4` and `shp5` should be visible). Here is the dictionary I made:

```
Dim Numbers As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of PowerPacks.Shape)) From {{1, New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape) From {shp4, shp5}}, {2, New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape) From {shp2, shp3}}}
```

Here is the code for the button (`btn1`):

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click

    Dim Thing As PowerPacks.Shape = Numbers(1)(0)
    Thing.Visible = True

End Sub
```

When the program gets to the line that says `Thing.Visible = True`, it throws an error. It's a `NullReferenceException` that states `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Any ideas on how to fix this?

## Sources

### Source 1:

### [image: Image of a 7-Segment Display]
Source 2:

[image: My 7-Segment Display Visual Basic Form]

Comment: Firstly, why are you using `Lists` instead of arrays? Do you need to add or remove items? I would think not, so a `List` offers no advantage over an array but it does include overhead. You should arrays where they are appropriate and collections where they are not.

Comment: I would also tend to recommend using GDI+ to draw the segments rather than using `Shapes`. The PowerPacks are no longer supported for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming is not magic. It works pretty much as you'd expect. If you are getting `Nothing` out of your `List` within a `Dictionary` then you must be putting `Nothing` in. Did you use the debugger before posting? Did you actually look at the value of `shp2`, etc, when this line is executed:

```vb
Dim Numbers As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of PowerPacks.Shape)) From {{1, New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape) From {shp4, shp5}}, {2, New List(Of PowerPacks.Shape) From {shp2, shp3}}}
```

Based on your use of that `Numbers` variable in the second code snippet, it must be a member variable, which means that that first code snippet is outside any method, which means that it is executed before the class constructor, which means that no controls have been created at that time, which means that any fields that refer to controls can't be anything but `Nothing`. If you had put a breakpoint on that line and used the debugger, as you should have, then you'd have seen that.

The solution is not actually add the `Shapes` to the collection until they are created. That means after the call to `InitializeComponent`. That means that you can create your own constructor and do it there if you want, but that you should probably just do it in the `Load` event handler. Just declare the `Dictionary` variable without creating an object:

```vb
Private numbers As Dictionary(Of Integer, PowerPacks.Shape())
```

Note that I have provide an explicit access modifier, which you should ALWAYS do for all members, and also started the name with a lower-case letter, which you probably ought to do for all private fields. You then create the object in the `load` event handler:

```vb
numbers As New Dictionary(Of Integer, PowerPacks.Shape()) From {{1, {shp4, shp5}},
                                                                {2, {shp2, shp3}}}
```

I've taken the liberty of simplifying that by using arrays rather than `Lists` that add no value.

Comment: I do not know anything about arrays as we are yet to learn about them. But thank you for your answer and your time. Yes, the problem was the fact that I was declaring and assigning a value to the `Numbers` variable before the Form had actually initialized all the components. I changed it to what you said and now have declared it in the `Public Class`, but am assigning a value to it in the `load` event handler and it works now. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's a bit of a failure of whatever course/class you're taking that you have learned about complex collections before something as fundamental as arrays. A `List` is basically a dynamic array, i.e. you get and set items by index in the same way but the collection will grow and shrink as you add and remove items, where an array is fixed-size. The `List` actually maintains an array internally and adds a layer of complexity to achieve that dynamic behaviour. If you don't need the behaviour, you shouldn't add the complexity. The array is no harder to use for you in this scenario.

Comment: And as for the debugger, I'm not that experienced in `VB.net`, so I didn't really know how to. I know it seems dumb. And if my post made it seem like I jumped straight up to ask this question, no; I did a lot of Googling for about half-an-hour before asking this question. But I understand now if oyu're frustrated by this. I also know that programming is not magic, but just forgetting a simple thing such as checking the debugger can make it seem so. I am sorry if this post angered you in any way, but I really am appreciative of the tip and help you have given. Thank you.

Comment: It's a year 10 high-school class. We haven't learnt any of that, I just wanted to do something more than write out 100 lines of code for every single button on the form. I hope you can understand.

Comment: I will also look into arrays right now. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @BrightBulb123 laziness / dislike of duplication is a great instinct to have as a developer.  You're getting some frustration in response to your question because there are a lot of beginner-level questions here from theoretically professional developers (vs. students at a beginning level).

Answer (score 1):

On your 7-Segment Display Form, I would use a `List (of String)` containing which rectangles are turned on for each dictionary key (number).  This would require first programatically adding the 7 shapes onto the form (looks like you already coded that), and then in each button (for numbers) just pick off which rectangles are turned on and change their background color.  "Front loading" all the Shapes (rectangles) into the Dictionary is probably unnecessary, since they are already manually fixed on the Form.  If they are not, then pull out the code that places them on the form and run that first, one time, when the form loads.  Using this approach, you don't have to worry about Shapes any more.

In Form 1, add:

```
Dim dicRSBackColor As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))
Dim SC As New ShapeContainer
```

In Form1_Load, add the following:

```
   'define each of the 7 rectangles using, e.g.: 
    Dim myrec4 As New RectangleShape
    myrec4.Name = "shp4"
    myrec4.Visible = True
    myrec4.BringToFront()
    'add locations and size to myrec4
    myrec4.Top=100
    myrec4.Left=100
    myrec4.Width=10
    myrec4.Height=100
    'then add myrec4 to Shape container
    SC.Shapes.Add(myrec4)
    'add myrec4 to Form1
    Me.Controls.Add(myrec4)
    'do the above for all 7 rectangleshapes

    'For the dictionary, add number 1's rectangleshape (turned on)
    Dim mylist As List(Of String)
    mylist.Add("shp4")
    mylist.Add("shp5")
    dicRSBackColor.Add(1, mylist)
    'add number 2 rectangles (turned on)
    mylist.Clear()
    mylist.Add("shp1")
    mylist.Add("shp3")
    mylist.Add("shp4")
    mylist.Add("shp6")
    mylist.Add("shp7")
    dicRSBackColor.Add(2, mylist)
    'continue until all 7 rec's added
```

Last, in the button _Click for number 1, use the following:

```
'First change background color of all rectangleshapes to Form1's back color
For Each rs As RectangleShape In Me.SC.Shapes
    rs.BackColor = Me.BackColor
Next
'Now pull the list of shapes that are turned on for number 1 using the dictionary
Dim mylist1 As List(Of String)
mylist1 = dicRSBackColor(1) 'you're pulling the value for key=1, which is a list of strings
'use a double loop and find out when the list value is the same as the name of the rectangleshape, and then set the back color to orange
For Each item In mylist1
    For Each rs As RectangleShape In Me.SC.Shapes
        If item = rs.Name Then rs.BackColor = Color.Orange
    Next
Next
```